# How do you extract macros programmatically from OpenOffice.org Writer document using .NET?

Tags: .net, automation, openoffice.org, libreoffice

How do you extract the Macro code from an OpenOffice.org Writer document using the .NET API?

I got an answer to the ["Office 2007" version of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49724/programmatically-extract-macro-vba-code-from-word-2007-docs), but we are evaluating OpenOffice as an alternative -- if anyone has any experience with this, any tips or resources would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a quite old question, but nowadays there are several answers that could be useful:

1. [How to create an OpenOffice document in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273787/how-to-create-an-openoffice-document-in-net?rq=1)
2. [How do I programmatically save a document in OpenOffice.org?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022846/how-do-i-programmatically-save-a-document-in-openoffice-org?rq=1)