# How do I programmatically save a document in OpenOffice.org?

Tags: c#, openoffice.org, uno

I'd like to save a `TextDocument` created through OpenOffice.org UNO to a file on the disk. What is the best way to do this?

Edit: This is the C# code that I ended up using. `document` is an `XTextDocument`.

```
protected void Save (string path)
{
    string url = "file://" + path;
    PropertyValue [] propertyValues = {
        new PropertyValue {
            Name = "FilterName",
            Value = new Any ("writer8")
        }
    };
    ((XStorable) document).storeAsURL (url, propertyValues);
}
```

Comment: I'm working in C#, but if you answer in a different language, I can translate it to C#.

Comment: Be careful what you wish for - ++++[>+++++<-]>[<+++++>-]+<+[>[>+>+<<-]++>>[<<+>>-]>>>[-]++>[-]+>>>+[[-]++++++>
>>]<<<[[<++++++++<++>>-]+<.<[>----<-]<]<<[>>>>>[>>>[-]+++++++++<[>-<-]+++++++++
>[-[<->-]+[<<<]]<[>+<-]>]<<-]<<-]

Comment: Didn't know OOo was scriptable in BF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [XStorable.storeToURL()](http://api.openoffice.org/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/frame/XStorable.html#storeToURL) (or storeAsURL).

Edit: You need to pass a `FilterName` with the output format. Example (in Python 'cause that's simpler):

```
properties = ( PropertyValue('FilterName', 0, 'writer8', 0), )
document.storeToURL('file:///path/to/document.odt', properties)
```

Comment: `storeToURL ()` and `storeAsURL ()` require 2 parameters, even though the documentation says the second is optional. I tried passing `null` as the second, but I get an IOException. I'm looking around the documentation now, but do you know how to fix this? If I can figure out how to set the default URL of the document, I can just use the `store ()` method and avoid the whole issue.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. I added the C# version of this code to my question.