# Extract/Display Macro (VBA) from .xls files using VB6 (without opening Excel)

Tags: vba, vb6, extract

I understand it is possible to do so using Excel macro, see: [Programmatically extract macro (VBA) code from Word 2007 docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49724/programmatically-extract-macro-vba-code-from-word-2007-docs), but what I want to do here is to use VB6 to make an application which does the same thing.

I am having problem on how to point to the Excel workbook (`thisworkbook.VBproject` is used in the example above).

Is it possible to select any .xls file from the hd, say `c:\try.xls`, and extract/show its macros? Please advise!

Comment: Excel Macros are tokenized, which makes it difficult to extract the macro, without using Excel.

Answer (score 2):

Set a reference to the Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library (or whatever version required) and use the workbook's VBProject.VBComponents collection e.g.

```
Sub ExportCode()
  Dim app As Excel.Application
  Set app = New Excel.Application

  Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
  Set wb = Excel.Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Book2.xls")

  Dim strExt As String

  Dim VBComp As Object
  For Each VBComp In wb.VBProject.VBComponents
    Select Case VBComp.Type
      Case 2  ' Class module
        strExt = ".cls"
      Case 3  ' Form
        strExt = ".frm"
      Case 1  ' Standard module
        strExt = ".bas"
      Case 100  ' Document?
        strExt = ".cls"
      Case Else
        Stop  ' What else is there?
        strExt = ".cls"
    End Select

    VBComp.Export "C:\" & VBComp.Name & strExt
  Next
  wb.Close False
  app.Quit

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The following line:

```
Set wb = Excel.Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Book2.xls")
```

should be

```
Set wb = app.Workbooks.Open("C:\Book2.xls")
```

Comment: "Should be"? It's a worthy refactoring but the improvement is negligible.

Answer (score 1):

[VbaDiff](http://www.technicana.com/products/vbadiff.html) can read Excel macros directly from the Excel file, exactly in the way you describe. 
If you need programmatic access, there is an Enterprise version with an API. You can do some quite fun stuff with this, like in [these examples](http://www.technicana.com/enterprise-version/api-examples.html).

Full disclosure - I built this product. I kept coming across similar problems to what Dean was having and decided that the time had come to solve it once and for all!

Comment: I hate them too Andre, but the fully functioning demo model doesn't work so well for this kind of recovery functionality. All the other great functions are in there though. Thanks for taking a look at VbaDiff.

Comment: I've taken out the 30 line limit for the main diff functionality.

Comment: Great! The tool is absolutely useful. I recommend it!