# How to use version control with VBA code?

Tags: svn, version-control, vba

I am developing a VBA application which is quite large. I want to use SVN for that  application developing.

How can I split my modules from the Excel document and how to upload my modules separately to source control?

Please help me.

Comment: Although this question asks about SVN, and this alternate question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36024342/how-to-put-excel-vba-into-git/53160775#53160775) asks about Git, they are both really asking the same thing: how do I export/import in bulk a bunch of VBA modules from/to a workbook. The choice of VCS can then be made independently.

Answer (score 10):

Check out this excel addin https://github.com/hilkoc/vbaDeveloper .

It exports all your vba code automatically, as soon as you save your workbook. You can also easily import it again, when you open a workbook. It all work very nicely.

As a bonus, it comes with a code formatter that you can run within the vba editor, so you can format your code as you write.

Answer (score 8):

I wrote a small tool to help with putting VBA code under version control, *without* requiring anything from Excel, or locking you into any specific version-control system. It can either extract modules from an Office file to a folder, or publish modules from a folder to an Office file. In either case it accesses the Office file directly, not through Excel. It's available [on GitHub](https://github.com/chelh/VBASync/releases):

> Microsoft Office VBA code is usually held in binary format, making proper version control difficult. VBA Sync Tool synchronizes macros between a VBA-enabled file and a folder, enabling easy version control using Git, SVN, Mercurial, or any other VCS.

To start, select the **Extract VBA from Office file** option, then select the locations of your repository (or where you'd like to start one) and the Office file. The tool will compare the two locations and show all the differences:

[image: VBA Sync Tool after selecting folder and file locations]

If you want to extract everything (typical for setting up a repository), just click **OK**. If you want to be more selective, you can untick specific files (for example some form designs that you know haven't changed) and then proceed. If you set up a diff tool (under File → Settings), you can double-click on a module to view its changes.

After a merge, follow the same procedure, but select the **Publish VBA to Office file** option. When you hit **Apply** or **OK**, the tool will write the combined code into the Office file.

Answer (score 3):

With file->export file you can export the individual classes.

That's one way to split the modules out - temporarily or otherwise.

Once you've done that, you can then create an SVN repository. I won't go into instructions for that as it's all over the internet, but here's a starting point:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch05s02.html

Comment: Why not export all the classes/forms/modules automatically in one go? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49724/programmatically-extract-macro-vba-code-from-word-2007-docs/49796#49796

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49724/programmatically-extract-macro-vba-code-from-word-2007-docs/49796#49796) on how to automatically extract all modules/forms/classes to text files. Which will make them more manageable in SVN.