# Get all macros from Microsoft Word (using automation)

Tags: c++, macros, mfc, ms-word, ms-office

I'm writing a C++ MFC program which automate MS Word using their [interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/microsoft.office.interop.word%28v=office.12%29).

From my app I was able to open MS Word, open macro window but I need to retrieve all macros from a combobox and add them in my app and so later on user can choose which macro he wants to apply to some document.

Can retrieving be done with GetProperty method? If it can you can show me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Document.VBProject to get access to the VBA code (to get to the macros in the document). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49724/programmatically-extract-macro-vba-code-from-word-2007-docs) is how to do it in word using VBA/C#. You can just rewrite that code using C++.

Note that MFC is not the easiest way to work with word automation, but you can do it using MFC as well. There is more than one approach available when you do automation with MFC. You may do this with MFC-only-way (i.e. in style from 90x, using object wrappers), or use e.g. #import directive.

GetProperty is basically a generic method, which can be to get some properties of the object it is applied to, i.e. it is not specific for macros.

Note also that end-user must have "Trust programmatic access to VBA project" enabled to allow your code to get the macros (this is a checkbox in word security settings, turned OFF by default). May be a show-stopper.

Comment: Thanks Nikolay, I made it.